# Are "consider" and "take into account" always interchangeable?

Tags: idioms, synonyms

I had this sentence in my writing:

"The images were adjusted for white balance to **take into account** differences in light environment."

One of my supervisors thought it was wordy, and corrected it to:

"The images were adjusted for white balance to **consider** differences in light environment."

The correction sounds very odd to my ears. But all discussions and examples I found online more or less state that they are interchangeable. Is this true?

Comment: *Consider* can take an object complement: "I considered him a friend" not "I took into account him a friend"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your point is well illustrated by the Cambridge dictionary . Others are similar.

> to take into account = to consider or remember something when judging a situation
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-into-account)

> consider =  spend time thinking about possibility or making decision;  think carefully about something
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-into-account)

But there are hints of difference. Merriam Webster does not give *consider* as a synonym for *take into account*:

> Synonyms & Antonyms of take into account: to give consideration to (as unexpected circumstances or contingencies)
>
> Taking into account the possibility of stormy weather, we decided to spring for a cabin instead of pitching a tent.
>
> Synonyms for take into account: allow (for), consider, factor (in or into), provide (for), regard.
>
> Words Related to take into account: accommodate, adapt, adjust, condition, anticipate, contemplate, envisage, expect, foresee, assume, presume, presuppose, plan

I suggest that small differences exist that depend on the use of *account*. As a financial analogy, taking something into *account* is to enter it into the account along with other items, where it inevitably will determine something of the final outcome. To take something into the account of a series of events inserts it in the record of events. To take account of points of argument is to use them to resolve the final conclusion.

To take into account is therefore sometimes different from mere consideration, which may have no influence on the final outcome or on the record. For example, when writing an article about meteorological phenomena on a rotating spherical earth, I may consider others' assertions that the the earth is flat, but I reject them and my article does not take them into account. (Note that my article is not about the flat earth controversy itself; it is about weather systems on a rotating sphere.)

On the other hand, if the weather forecast is poor, I not only consider it but I act on it by taking it into account when planning my voyage.

Comment: This. A way to make the OP sentence a little bit less wordy would be to say "... adjusted for white balance *account for* differences..."

Comment: So is it safe to say that in my case, as the differences in light environment were always corrected for the images, "take into account" is more accurate than "consider"?

Comment: I would use take into account for the reasons I suggest in my answer. One does not need to adjust an image in order to consider the environment.

Comment: The problem is that *consider* in particular has multiple meanings. It can refer to a thought process ("She considered whether to kill him") or an individual factor ("She considered whether to use his gun to kill him"), but *take into account* typically implies less of a thought process and more of a factor informing a decision ("She took into account the wind when firing the gun").

Comment: The first sentence uses the usual 'cater for / allow for [[Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take%20into%20account)] / make allowance for / accommodate' sense of 'take into account'. Cambridge seems to demand no more than 'give some thought to' here (as one sense, at least). But the definition of 'consider'  does not even hint at corrective measures.  So, as corrective measures **are** applied, 'take into account' is the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native English speaker, but I have written two academic books in English. I make a very clear distinction between the two words in this sense:

> The word "consider" means it is necessary to think about the topic but it can be excluded; whereas "take into account" means it is necessary to think about the topic but it cannot be excluded.

Note that this is actually a citation from the article [What is the meaning of "consider" & "take into account" in ISO 14001:2015](https://emsmastery.com/2021/01/27/what-is-the-meaning-of-consider-take-into-account-in-iso-140012015/), with which I wholeheartedly agree.

But I would be glad if native English speakers could confirm or refute whether this thinking is correct.

Comment: “Consider” is something people do; “in consideration of” is a way to use the word while avoiding the thinker.

Comment: That may be an arbitrary distinction in an ISO document but it doesn't reflect how they're used by normal people in regular English.

Comment: @StuartF I assume normal people means non-scientists in your comment?  This issue bugs me for very long time, so I will open a new question to clear it out.

Comment: @StuartF In your opinion, are both constructs equally valid for normal people, or is one of them preferred?

Answer (score 0):

[Take into account](https://www.crosswordsolver.com/clue/TAKE-INTO-ACCOUNT) can also mean to "note" something such as to physically write something down. But I would not say the same for "consider", which is more about mentally accounting for something.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider certain information but not necessarily take it into account in your calculations because you deem it irrelevant.